# Git fatal: ambiguous argument '|': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: git, nuke-build

When I open git bash and execute the follow command, I have no problem!

```
  git log --no-renames --after=’2020-01-01’ --diff-filter=D --summary | grep 'delete mode' > log.txt
```

But When I try to execute this:

```
GitTasks.Git(@"log --no-renames --after=’2020-01-01’ --diff-filter=D --summary | grep 'delete mode' > files.20.exclude", @"D:\folder\myproject");
```

I Get those errors:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '|': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

fatal: ambiguous argument '>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

What I have to do to get the same result?

Comment: The "pipe" `|` and all that follows is not part of any git command so it makes no sense to hand it to GitTasks.Git.

Comment: The piping (`|`) and the redirection (`>`) are features of the shell (Bash). It parses the command line, identifies the commands to run then runs `git` with its list of arguments (everything between `git` and `|`), runs `grep` with one argument (`delete mode`), connects the output stream of `git` to the input stream of `grep` (`|`) and the output stream of `grep` to the file `log.txt` (`>`). When you use `GitTasks.Git` a shell is not involved. The string is parsed to pieces (separated by spaces) and all the pieces are fed as arguments to Git. There is no shell to do the magic described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem, I was executing bash commands expecting to work with git like @axiac commented!

For resolving my problem, I wrote the log to a file without 
`| grep 'delete mode'` and `> log.txt` and removed everything that I didn't want.